# Изменение параметров тега при подгрузке контента

Tags: ajax

Имеется такой код:

```js
$(document).on('click','.read-more',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id') || 0;
    // Вставляем полученный контент в HTML блок с id="content"

    $('#content')
    .append($('<div>')
    .load("https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&sentences=1&start-with-lorem=1&format=html"));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="getContent">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <a class="read-more" data-id="0" href="#">Подробнее</a>
</div>
```

Как изменить скрипт, что бы в параметре data-id значение при каждом нажатии на ссылку увеличивалось на 12

Answer (score 0):

Все таки смог разобраться сам, вот код, может кому пригодится:

```js
$(document).on('click','.read-more',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id') || 0;
    var data = parseInt($(".read-more").attr("data-id"), 10)+12;

    $('#content')
    .append($('<div>')
    .load("https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&sentences=1&start-with-lorem=1&format=html"));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="getContent">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <a class="read-more" data-id="0" href="#">Подробнее</a>
</div>
```